# Иерархия страниц WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Наверное, вопрос глупый, но все же. Читала про иерархию страниц на wp-kama, для блога все понятно. Но если у меня многостраничник плюс блог, как быть с такими сайтами?Каждую страницу сайта задавать создавая page-about.php и т.д., а для блога использовать index.php и single.php для записи?Или есть какие-то более правильные способы?

Comment: Для страниц: контакты. о нас и т.д. вы можете использовать отдельные шаблоны, а можете подключить конструктор, Elementor к примеру и настраивать дизайн/наполнять контентом через него.

Comment: У камы такого не может быть написано.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ваши страницы одинаковы - используйте `page.php` для них. Если какие-то из страниц не такие одинаковые, как другие - делайте для них отдельные шаблоны. Для каждой "неодинаковой" страницы нужен будет свой шаблон. Но для страниц одного вида можно создать один шаблон:

```
<?php /* Template Name: My Custom Page */ ?>
```

и подключать его в админке для всех страниц нужного вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если ваша многостраничная часть похожа на каталог - вам лучше использовать [собственные типы записей](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/), у них будут свои шаблоны.

Comment: У меня все страницы абсолютно разные. Только что снова перечитала wp-kama, они для блога предлагают на выбор либо home.php либо index.php.
Я пока вижу это так: home.php главная, остальные типа contact.php, delivery.php и т.д. с выбором шаблона, а на блог тогда что?По логике вп-кама опять же остается только index.php
Собственные типы записей Вы имеете ввиду register_post_type() ?Просто с полями пока вроде все понятно, не могу со страничками разобраться

Comment: Если все абсолютно разные - то для каждой страницы свой шаблон. `home.php` для главной, `index.php` - для списка записей блога (в `/wp-admin/options-reading.php` вы можете указать конкретные страницы), `single.php` - для самих записей

Answer (score 1):

> Каждую страницу сайта задавать создавая page-about.php и т.д., а для
>   блога использовать index.php и single.php для записи?Или есть какие-то
>   более правильные способы?

Никакие файлы создавать не нужно, если не требуются какие-то особые функции или дизайн **отдельных** страниц.
Просто надо писать. И писать в ЗАПИСИ, присваивая им РУБРИКИ.
А СТРАНИЦЫ оставить для статичной информации - "о сайте", "контакты" и тп.

См мои старые объяснялки: https://ru.wordpress.org/support/topic/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE/#post-155549